# MySQL query with joins returning only one result

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
  f.Codigo_interno AS f_internal_code,
  f.Nombre AS f_name,
  p.Codigo_practica AS p_internal_code,
  p.Nombre AS p_name,
  p.Nomenclador_nacional AS p_external_code,
  fpl.Codigo_plan AS fpl_internal_code,
  fpl.Plan AS fpl_name,
  fp.code AS fp_code,
  fp.description AS fp_description,
  fp.enabled AS fp_enabled
FROM financier_practice_disabled_in_plan fpd
  INNER JOIN obra_social f on fpd.financier_id = f.Codigo_interno
  INNER JOIN practicas p on fpd.practice_id = p.Codigo_practica
  INNER JOIN obra_social_plan fpl on fpl.Codigo_plan = fpd.plan_id
  INNER JOIN financier_practice fp on fp.practice_id = p.Codigo_practica AND fp.financier_id = f.Codigo_interno
WHERE fpd.financier_id = 10
```

It outputs:

```
10  OSDE    11.11.02    Práctica 1  11.11.02    111 210 10.10.02    Descripción 1   0
```

But there are two records in financier_practice_disabled_in_plan table:

```
practice_id financier_id plan_id
11.11.02      10            111
11.11.03      10            112
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can change it to a left join so it would still display rows from left-table even if it did not match with the other tables. Anyway, we would need the content of the other tables to help further.

Comment: @BennjoeMordeno thanks, those are foreign keys, so related content exists. I will try your suggestion

Comment: @BennjoeMordeno it indeed worked, I see the fp_* fields are null, I will check